# perl command to parse a text file and spool output into different files based on string pattern

Tags: perl, command-line, scripting, pattern-matching

I am running a perl script which I spool into a text file in one of the computer drives say D:.

The output (text) file would look like this:

```
January/huhuharf
January/asdgfsdf
January/asegfeargterg
January/4t3t46456786949rhjyrj
January/asdgfasdfgdfgdf
.
.
.
.
.
.

February/asdvgaretrterre
February/34523452345345
February/054656445
.
.
.
.
.
.
March/q235345
March/asfwetrert
March/gqergergh34
March/12353245
.
.
```

Could you please let me know of a command or script that will parse through the text file and split this output into multiple text files based on string pattern. For Eg: I would want all the lines containing "January" in one text file, similarly "all the lines containing "February" should be in another file, etc.

Furthermore, if there are lines like:

```
February/January/asdvgaretrterre
February/January/34523452345345
.
.
```

I would want these lines to be stored in another text file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [open](http://p3rl.org/open) to open a file, specify the `>` mode to open it for writing. You can use a regular expression match to extract the month, then just compare it to the remembered value from the previous iteration. It it's different, open a new file.

So, basically, something like

```
 perl -ne '
          ($file) = m%^(.+)/%;                       # Extract the month(s).
          open $OUT, ">", $file if $file ne $opened; # Open the file if not yet opened.
          $opened = $file;                           # Remember the last opened file.
          print {$OUT} $_;                           # Print the line to it.
         ' < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#iterate one line at a time from STDIN or specified filename(s)
while (<>) {
    #split content - note 'greedy' regex means as much as possible gets read into
    #first capture group.
    my ( $location, $content ) = m,(.*)/(.*),;
    #replace slashes, so February/January becomes February_January
    $location =~ tr,/,_,;

    #open a file based on that, print content
    open( my $output, ">>", "$location.out" ) or warn $!;
    print {$output} $content;
    close($output);
}
```